# next.js webpack failure on files with shebang: Module parse failed: Unexpected character '#'

Tags: javascript, webpack, next.js, ethereum, ganache

I am having trouble creating a webpage using next.js due to what seems as a webpack error in handling files starting with a shebang character. I am attempting to get the web page to interact with a local ethereum network set up with ganache-cli. Here is the error I am getting:

```
error - ./node_modules/ganache-cli/build/ganache-core.node.cli.js
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '#' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> #!/usr/bin/env node
```

Here is the index.js file:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import vault from '../ethereum/vault';

class VaultIndex extends Component {

  render() {
    return <div>test</div>
  }
}

export default VaultIndex;
```

The vault.js file that is imported starts with this require statement, where I suspect based on the error, things start getting dicey:

```
const ganache = require('ganache-cli');
```

I attempted to create a next.config.js file and load a plugin that should be able to handle these files that start with a shebang (https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-shebang-plugin) as per next.config.js documentation (https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/custom-webpack-config). Here is the next.config.js file:

```
const ShebangPlugin = require('webpack-shebang-plugin');

module.exports = {
  webpack: (config) => {

    config.plugins.push(new ShebangPlugin())

    return config
  },
}
```

When doing this, I get the following error:

```
ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000
info  - Using webpack 4. Reason: custom webpack configuration in next.config.js https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/webpack5
ReferenceError: Cannot access 'watcher' before initialization
    at D:\My stuff\Vault\node_modules\next\dist\server\hot-reloader.js:31:40
    at Watching.handler (D:\My stuff\Vault\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\webpack\bundle4.js:83932:17)
    at Watching._done (D:\My stuff\Vault\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\webpack\bundle4.js:94252:9)
    at onCompiled (D:\My stuff\Vault\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\webpack\bundle4.js:94201:26)
    at D:\My stuff\Vault\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\webpack\bundle4.js:74777:21
    at AsyncParallelHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (D:\My stuff\Vault\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\webpack\bundle4.js:128919:10), <anonymous>:19:1)
    at AsyncParallelHook.lazyCompileHook (D:\My stuff\Vault\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\webpack\bundle4.js:128856:20)
    at D:\My stuff\Vault\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\webpack\bundle4.js:74776:20
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (D:\My stuff\Vault\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\webpack\bundle4.js:128919:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (D:\My stuff\Vault\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\webpack\bundle4.js:128856:20)
```

I'm not sure what to make of it. I am very new to using next.js, or javascript for that matter. Is there a simple way to deal with this error? Please explain in lay terms (:

Thanks,

Uri